# MySQL installation on Mac OSX 10.9.4

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to install mysql on my mac OSX maverics.

**I have followed this guide and executed the following command:**

**Guide:**

```
http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-mavericks/
```

I have executed the following command in terminal:

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

**I got this error:**

```
rocky$ bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
Downloading MySQL Installers ... may take a few moments
######################################################################## 100.0%
...
...
Installing MySQL, administrator password required ...
Password:
Installing MySQL start up items...
Password:
installer: Package name is MySQL Startup Item
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
...
...
Click Install to install the MySQL preferance pane
...
...
...
sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found
sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 126: SORRY, MySQL IS NOT RUNNING ... THERE MUST BE A PROBLEM: command not found
```

Am I missing something or should I install anything?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue.

Steps to follow:

1) I restarted my MAC
2) I removed everything I have installed till now.
3) Did a fresh installation using script and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a GUI way,
use this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and download your version.
Install mysql and the options.

After that you will find the mysql option in your System Preferences.

I used that way on my MacBook Pro and works.

Comment: But I believe there is no mysql for Mac OSX 10.9.4. They have it for 10.7 and I have seen users having problems installing. So I didn't go ahead! Please enlighten me if you're using latest 10.9.4 (stable)

Comment: I downloaded the dmg from the website, launched the mysql-5.6.19-osx-10.7-x86_64.pkg, after i launched MySQL.prefPanel. After that u will have the voice in System Preferences. Check if u have the directory mysql on your mac. check at this path "/usr/local/" if u have the dir. Probably you have a directory called mysql-<version>, rename it in mysql and it will works

Comment: agreed. but I think a ONE line script execution will take care of everything right :D Anyways, Appreciate your response sir.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it with HomeBrew

```
brew install mysql
```

Make sure that you have command line tools if you get some error

```
xcode-select --install
```